# How to show AlertDialog on checkbox click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to show a popup or `AlertDialog` after clicking on `Checkbox`. I can't find anything like `onPressed` in `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Checkbox` does have `onChanged` callback which returns the value of current checked status, short sample:

```
bool _checked = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Checkbox(
      value: _checked,
      onChanged: (checked) {
        setState(() => _checked = checked);
        if (_checked) {
          // show dialog if check box is checked
          showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(title: Text("Dialog")));
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CheckBox` widget don't have `onPressed` function but `onChanged`.

See the [Official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html)